# Bootstrap images in grid that holdes different sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m currently an aspiring frontend developer. I´ve been assigned to create the markup and style of the following image

[Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2frK.jpg)

I´m currently using twitter bootstrap 5, however I can´t seem to make the right adjustement.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid p-0 bg-wabe h-100">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg link-light mb-4 border-b">
                <a class="navbar-brand m-4" href="#">
                    brand
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 nav-fill w-100">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active link-light border-r" aria-current="page" href="#">LUGARES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link link-light border-r" href="#">CATEGORIA</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link link-light border-r" href="#">EVENTOS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link link-light border-r" href="#">CUPONES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link link-light" href="#">CUENTA</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container-xxl">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 p-0">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530863666585-c8996c9f729c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80" class="img-fluid mb-2" alt="img1">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530863666585-c8996c9f729c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80" class="img-fluid" alt="img1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 p-0 pl-1 m-0">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561807367-a1ff826a51e6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80g" class="img-fluid" alt="img1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 p-0 pl-1 m-0">   
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561807367-a1ff826a51e6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" class="img-fluid" alt="img1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
    
</html>
```

Should I use them as background images and use the cover property?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify your question and point us to the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need with modern css.

You can just add this css:

```
img {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   object-fit:cover;
   object-position:center;
}
```

It will work as if it were a `background-image`

Comment: It worked great for the images on the right however on the left you have images that now are smaller. https://i.imgur.com/flltGan.jpg

Comment: Nevermind, I added the h-50 class in the images and added what you recomended and it worked like a charm! THANK YOU!